Neovim command to create print statement for Python function arguments
As the title suggests, I had the idea to create a command that can automatically write a print statement for all arguments to the current function I am in.  Initially, I wanted to do this for Python functions - as I find myself doing this manually as a debug tool.
For example, take the Python function:
def my_func(a: int, b: str) -> None:
  ...

If my cursor is within the function definition and I run the command PythonPrintParams, I want to write the following to the first line of the function:
print(
  f"a={a}, "
  f"b={b}"
)

I want to write a Lua function that can do this using treesitter and then setup a Neovim autocommand.  So far I have:
local ts_utils = require('nvim-treesitter.ts_utils')

local function list_fn_params()
  local node = ts_utils.get_node_at_cursor()

  while node and node:type() ~= 'function_definition' do
    node = node:parent()
  end

  if not node then
    print("Could not find params, cursor not inside a function.")
    return
  end

  local param_nodes = node:field('parameters')
  if param_nodes  then
    for i, param_node in ipairs(param_nodes) do
      print("  Node", i, "type:", param_node:type())
      print("  Node text:", vim.inspect(ts_utils.get_node_text(param_node)))
    end
  end
end

vim.api.nvim_create_user_command('PythonPrintParams', function()
  list_fn_params()
end, {})


This ends up printing:
  Node 1 type: parameters
  Node text: { "(", "    a: int, b: str", ")" }

This is a good start but then requires some manual parsing that I think will get messy.  How can I parse deeper to get the variable and then write my print statement?  Is there an alternate route with the LSP API that makes identifying args easier?
I did spend time with the py-tree-sitter docs https://github.com/tree-sitter/py-tree-sitter/tree/master.

Have you considered writing a simple python decorator? That seems like an easier approach.

That is something I've done in the past.  One downside to the decorator is that it needs to be added to the python repo while this command would work anywhere I have my editor.  I also think this command could be extended to support other languages.
At least half of the motivation here is learning treesitter and building with Lua too :)

I can get behind that if this is for help with quick debugging. For committed code, I caution against generated code that's later edited by developers and not easy to regenerate. Java IDEs used to be pretty notorious for this (for things like builder class patterns and hashing methods). Later on when you inevitably want to change the generated outputs, its a brutal manual task to find and replace and re-modify the code that has been committed. Libraries and decorators have the key advantage of being refactorable, although require some more upfront cost.

e.g. right now, Python now has a nice feature where you can just write f"{a=}, {b=}" to get similar outputs to f"a={a}, b={b}" :)

Very nice!  Good points, and yes, this would just be for debugging.  Could also just get better at running a debugger in neovim.

Get tree and node at your cursor
  local cursor_row, cursor_col = unpack(vim.api.nvim_win_get_cursor(0))

  cursor_row = cursor_row - 1

  local parser = vim.treesitter.get_parser(0)

  local tree = parser:parse()[1]

  local root = tree:root()

 local node = root:named_descendant_for_range(cursor_row, cursor_col, cursor_row, cursor_col)

Go through nodes find function_definition in range of your cursor,
take its params and add print to first line of that function
  while node do
    if node:type() == "function_definition" then
      local start_row, _, end_row, _ = node:range()

      if cursor_row >= start_row and cursor_row <= end_row then
        print("Cursor is inside function")

        for child in node:iter_children() do
          if child:type() == "parameters" then
            local args_list = {}

            for param in child:iter_children() do
             
              if param:type() == "identifier" then
                local arg_name = vim.treesitter.get_node_text(param, 0)

                table.insert(args_list, string.format("%s={%s}", arg_name, arg_name))
              end
            end

            if #args_list ~= 0 then
              local args_string = table.concat(args_list, ", ")


              local print_statement = string.format('   print(f"%s")', args_string)

              vim.api.nvim_buf_set_lines(0, start_row + 1, start_row + 1, false, { print_statement })
            end

            return
          end
        end
      end
    
    node = node:parent()  
    end

  print("Cursor is not inside a function.") 
end

This handles only simple case,
def add_numbers(a, b):
    return a + b

To check for other type of params you can always run :InspectTree
and see what type you need for example to add default params
if param:type() == "default_parameter" then
 local arg_name = vim.treesitter.get_node_text(param:child(), 0)
end


Do you know why nvim_buf_set_lines cannot seem to accept a string with newlines in it?  If I try to pass in a string with newlines, I get `'replacement string' item contains newlines in function 'nvim_buf_set_lines'

I guess you tried to do something like this:
{ "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3" }. nvim_buf_set_lines expects an array of lines, corrected version would be: vim.api.nvim_buf_set_lines(0, 1, 1, false, { "Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3" }).
